# Iterate between number range in array and return value

Tags: php, json

I have a predicament where I have a range of weeks (5-8, 12-13, etc.) and from a `JSON` file I need to fill in the gaps between the ranges.

My JSON is as follows:

```
{
        "Name": "CHT2578/QGA/YEAR/Practical/01 <5-10, 12-16, 21-25, 27-32>",
        "Description": "TEAM PROJECT (MULTIMEDIA)",
        "Scheduled": "Checked",
        "Size": 25,
        "Required Staff Names": "Blogs, Joe",
        "Allocated Staff Name": "Blogs, Joe",
        "Allocated Location Name": "CW4/01",
        "Scheduled Weeks": "5-10, 12-16, 21-25, 27-32",
        "Scheduled Days": "Thursday",
        "Scheduled Start Time": "15:15",
        "Scheduled End Time": "17:15",
        "Who Scheduled": "test",
        "When Scheduled": "03/04/2014 10:13"
    }
```

So far I have managed to output as follows:

```
[19] => TEAM PROJECT (MULTIMEDIA) - CW5/03 - Wednesday - 5
[20] => TEAM PROJECT (MULTIMEDIA) - CW5/03 - Wednesday - 10
[21] => TEAM PROJECT (MULTIMEDIA) - CW5/03 - Wednesday -  12
[22] => TEAM PROJECT (MULTIMEDIA) - CW5/03 - Wednesday - 16
[23] => TEAM PROJECT (MULTIMEDIA) - CW5/03 - Wednesday -  21
[24] => TEAM PROJECT (MULTIMEDIA) - CW5/03 - Wednesday - 25
[25] => TEAM PROJECT (MULTIMEDIA) - CW5/03 - Wednesday -  27
[26] => TEAM PROJECT (MULTIMEDIA) - CW5/03 - Wednesday - 32
```

Using the following code I have managed the above output:

```
public function formatTimeTable($file){
    $this->file = $file;
    $info[] = null;

    $string = file_get_contents($file);
    $json = json_decode($string, true);

        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {

        // does it contain a ,
        if (strpos($value['Scheduled Weeks'], ',') !== false) { 

        // explode on the ,
        $ex = explode(",", $value['Scheduled Weeks']);
            for($i = 0; $i < count($ex); $i++){

              if (strpos($ex[$i], '-') !== false) { 
                $ex2 = explode("-", $ex[$i]);
                foreach($ex2 as $key => $val){

                        $info[] .= $value['Description'] . " - " . $value['Allocated Location Name'] . " - " . $value['Scheduled Days'] . " - " . $val;

                }

              }
              else{
                $info[] .= $value['Description'] . " - " . $value['Allocated Location Name'] . " - " . $value['Scheduled Days'] . " - " . $ex[$i];
              }
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            $info[] .=  $value['Description'] . " - " . $value['Allocated Location Name'] . " - " . $value['Scheduled Days'] . " - " . $value['Scheduled Weeks'];
        }
    }
    return $info;
}
```

My question is: *How am I able to +1 to the week range till it matches the final week?* I have tried:

- a while loop to iterate up the numbers.
- a for loop
- the foreach loop using key value pairs has been the closet I have gotten

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

Get a starting timestamp and an ending timestamp, and use those two as the bounds for your loop.  Then you can do something like this:

```
$timestamp = /* get starting timestamp */;
$stoptime = /* get ending timestamp */;
while($timestamp < $stoptime) {
   $curWeek = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp); // Or however you need to format the week..
   // .. the rest of your output code ..

   // Update timestamp to the next week
   $timestamp = strtotime('+1 week', $timestamp);
}
```